# Completions for directory paths don't work in command args

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, zshrc, tab-completion

Example: https://github.com/wadewegner/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_sfdx

I've noticed that completions for the directory stop working. For example, before using the above completion, you could type `sfdx force:command -d` and then use TAB to target a directory. However, after installing the completion, when you hit TAB after `-d` it doesn't try to autocomplete directories; instead, it only looks to the args defined in `_sfdx` for completions.

Is this something wrong with zsh-completions or the `_sfdx` completion? Could it be a misconfigured `.zshrc` file?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you know what you did when it stopped working ;-)

Comment: I created and loaded the `_sfdx` completion listed above. Expansion of directories in args hasn't ever worked. It's not like I had it working with this completion and then did something that caused it to stop working. Make sense?

Comment: Interestingly, it works for the command `docker load -i <TAB>`, so it must have something to do with how I set the args.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. adding `:file:_files` to the description of the argument works. Example: `'(-f|--definitionfile)'{-f,--definitionfile}'[path to a scratch org definition file]:file:_files' \`. Then when you type `-f <TAB>` it lists the local files. Dang, that was buried! Still haven't found docs that explain this well.

Comment: Can anyone think of a good reason why we shouldn't **always** default to `:file:_files`?